# How to put thorns on the surface of a plant?

Tags: hair

I  want to make a Spiny plant and I want make thorns on the surface of it with a specific angle .. I tried to use particle system (hair) but the thorns appear floating outside the mesh with random angles .. is there any way I can snap them on  the surface of the plant ? .

Comment: This task could be complicated by any number of details. The best way to get a useful answer would be to post your blend by way of https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: You will need to post some screenshots as a minimum before somebody will give you proper answer.

Comment: Shrink Wrap modifier should allow you this? Otherwise, take a look how Joakim Stigsson did the spikes on his amazing procedural cactus material (skip to 12mn50s into the youtube video). https://www.artstation.com/artwork/ZqldX

PS: discovered after seeing his interview on his gas station scene which is even more breathtaking at https://80.lv/articles/desert-gas-station-environment-production-breakdown/

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96350/how-do-i-add-spikes-my-characters-arms/96415#96415

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, when flower pedals were floating around the scene in random directions. I played around with particle settings and found the setting somewhere in the settings panel.

But solution to the floating particles I figured out much later. You have to make sure that your particle object is sitting right on top of its origin point. (orange dot) The particle system doesn't take the mesh and put it nicely o your object. Instead it takes the origin point and slaps it on top of the object. And when your particle object is far away from the origin, at just floats around somewhere else.

[image]

So yeah. Make sure your particle object is sitting on top of its origin (orange dot) and particle rotation settings you find somewher in the particle settings.  Hope this helped. Happy blending!