# Is there a way to ignore subdivided areas in a particle system?

Tags: particles

[image]

I subdivided a part of my model to sculpt there. 
I control the hair density with a texture painted texture.
The texture is just black and white.
Is there a way to make the density of the particle system uniform ?
In my understanding it shouldn`t have more hair in subdivided areas.
It should just put no hair on black and hair on white uniformly.

Comment: What are your particle settings, could you show us? They are important to diagnose particle related issues. Do you have the *Use modifier stack* option enabled? What about *Even DIstribution*?

Comment: Use weight painting to define where you want more or less particles or none. see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96350/how-do-i-add-spikes-my-characters-arms/96415#96415

Comment: i dont like weight paint cause it always requires a high vertex count to be as accurate as i often need it to be. With all ive done particle-wise i had much better results with texture paint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this settings:

1. Click Advanced to get extra settings
2. Click Even Distribution
3. Switch from Jittered to Random

[image]

Default settings:

[image]

Same geometry, but with this settings:

[image]

Comment: this worked flawlessly. Thank you for such a simple solution